# Help make a condition involving an array

Tags: magento2, php, php-7, customer-group, array

I have data from the server: `$this->getConfigData('groups') = "1,5,9,10"`

I need to make a condition, if one of these id matches the id from the custom group of the current user, then continue, if not, then deny.

I tried this approach, but it doesn't work, tell me how you can implement this logic

```
$customerGroup = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId(); -> 1
$array_key = array_keys((array)$this->getConfigData('groups'));        -> {0}[1]
if(!in_array($customerGroup, $array_key)){
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`explode` can split a string by a string into an array

Here is a reference sample.

```
$customerGroup = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();//1

$groupsInString = $this->getConfigData('groups'));//(string) "1,5,9,10"
$groupsInArray = explode(",",$this->getConfigData('groups'));//(array) [1,5,9,10]
if(!in_array($customerGroup, $groupsInArray)){
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What if the string comes empty and the value is null?

Comment: $groupsInArray will be an array containing empty string like [""]

Answer (score 0):

You receive a comma separated string from the db.
use `explode` (php native function) and then `in_array()`

docs for explode https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php